# How to call an external java function in XSLT from xsl:apply-templates

Tags: html, xslt, apache-fop

Apparently, it is impossible to directly call an external function from xsl:apply-templates. I have an XML node containing html tag for example :

```
<text>
    <ul>
        <li>
            blablablaba
        </li>
    </ul>
<text>
```

In my output, if I want the html tags to be applied, I need to use xsl:apply-templates select="text"/>. I can't use xsl:value-of since it won't consider the HTML. Now the problem is that I need to call a function which will transform the html tags so my code would be :

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="util:myFunction(text)"/>
```

However, this will result in an error, is there another way I could do this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, XSLT is already for transformation. What can it not do, what do you want it to do for you? Why do you need a Java function to do transformation while you are already using a tool meant for transformation? A little explanation on the problem would help in understanding your problem. Maybe XSLT is simply not right for you?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733300/how-to-call-external-java-function-in-xslt-file

Comment: [1] Do you declare the util: namespace as a java class ? [2] How are you calling xslt ? Do you include the jar with that class on the command line ?

Comment: How does the function code look? If you want to have the XSLT processor interact with Java and process the result of a function call into Java with apply-templates you need to be familiar with the API of the particular XSLT processor you use so that your function returns objects of the type or class or interface the XSLT processor consumes as nodes.

Comment: It is not a call problem because when I try calling it with xsl:value-of select="myFunction()"/> it works.

Also, the function code works when it's called with value-of.

Comment: @MartinHonnen 

it's a very simple function ...

    public static String myFunction(String text)
    {
        return text.replace("<li>", "&#8226;");
    }

Comment: Well the XSLT processor would pass in a node-set or sequence of nodes and you would need to write a function that processes such nodes and returns nodes. Your function seems to expect a string and do some string processing and return a string. That is not how XSLT processors operate, they operate on trees of nodes. Or how does the input look exactly, does the XML contain the HTML escaped as CDATA?

Comment: The HTML isn't escaped, I've tried using CDATA or &lt;ul&gt; etc. but nothing works... If I understand what your telling me is that apply-templates processes only nodes and that's why the function call works with xsl:value-of but not with xsl:apply-templates ?

Also, is there a way the html attributes of tags would be applied ? 

for example if I have <ul style="border:1pt solid black"> the style attributes will be ignored when printing with apply-templates

Comment: With XSLT 1.0 and 2.0 `apply-templates` is restricted to work with nodes so using a function that returns a string is not going to work. If you have separate questions then ask them in a separate question, it is not possible to address them in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to say is:  it appears to be impossible to use a function call to a Java function returning a string, in a context where XSLT requires an XPath expression which evaluates to a set of nodes.

Yes, that's impossible.

If you want to use the call `util:myFunction(text)` to select the nodes to which templates should be applied, you will need that function to return a set of nodes using whatever tree representation your XSLT processor is using.

It is almost certainly possible to do this, for XSLT processors that support user-supplied Java functions at all.  It is also almost certainly not the best solution for selecting input nodes to process; it's hard to imagine any node selection process that is easier in Java than in XSLT.